# VROne AR camera SDK?

Tags: vrone

We're interested in building an AR experience for the AROne. I've seen that Zeiss has an iPhone app that uses a camera passthrough (called Zeiss VR One AR). Does Zeiss provide any support or SDKs for this AR functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think so, but it is fairly easy to do by yourself, you just have to put a webcamtexture in front of the camera pair.